# is there something wrong with array.size?

Tags: c++

I want to give in a string into an array from keybord, so that i can count how many letters it has with for loop

I tried to buil and run the code but i doesnt work actually and there an error but I dont really understand the error and the way to fix them. The error is :

> request for member size in Bao( my Array), which is of none class type

Here is my code:

```
char Bao[100];
cout<<"Give me a sentence"<<endl;
cin.getline(Bao, 100, '\n');
cout<< Bao.size()<<endl;
```

Comment: Arrays don't have members. So whats wrong with `Bao.size()` is that it doesn't exist.

Comment: are you confusing c-style arrays with `std::array` ? What makes you think `Bao.size` should work?

Comment: there isnt much more to say than what the error message already tells you

Comment: Why are you using C arrays - *why*? Use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: ...or `std::string`

Comment: It seems you may be trying to print the size of the string obtained. Beware that arrays cannot change size in C++. `Bao` contains a string fewer than 100 characters but it's actual size is always 100. The size of the string is not encoded in the type or in the string's value. The string will be terminated by a `\0`. You may be looking for `strlen`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Size Member Function Compile Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326807/array-size-member-function-compile-error)

Comment: BTW, you can access `std::string` with array notation and loop through each character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you shouldn't even be using an array. Use `std::string`.
Here's some sample code that accomplishes the same thing as the code you posted:

```
std::string sentence;
std::cout << "Give me a sentence" << std::endl;
std::cin.getline(sentence, 100, '\n');
std::cout << "Scentence is " << sentence.size() << " bytes" << std::endl;
```

EDIT: using getline() for the spacebar bug.

Comment: but if in your code if I give spacebar in, it counts no longer correctly.

Comment: your code is doing something different than OPs. OP reads till `\n` you read only till space

Answer (score 1):

There is no function 'size' in a c++ array. You have to use

```
sizeof(array)
```

which gives the size of the array in bytes. To get the true size of the array use

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

which divides the size of the array with the size of a single element in the array giving you the number of elements.

Also, why are you using an array in this instance? It seems like a string might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I try to count the number of letter excluding "space". But still have no idea

Comment: Be aware that this method does not give the length of the C-Style string inside the array.  See also `strlen()`.