# Calling list.size() method gives error "expression must have class type"

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate over a list using `for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++)` where `options` is the list I need to iterate over. The error I get says,

```
expression must have class type.
```

I've tried `(int) options.size()`
within the for loop as well as `int length = options.size()` before the for loop, to no avail. What am I doing wrong??? Here is the full function; the list, `options[]`, is passed to the function with three items.

```
    int getChoice(string options[], int low, int high) {
        // Method variables:
        bool legal;     // True if input is valid, false otherwise
        string valid;   // List of valid inputs
        string entry;   // Temporary holder for user input
        int input;      // Return variable for user entry

        // Assign values to variables:
        legal = false;
        valid = "0123456789";

        // Print options, get/test user input:
        while (cont) {
            int length = options.size();  // didn't work
            (int) options.size() >> length; // didn't work
            for (int i = 0; i < options.size; i++) { // didn't work
                cout << i << ". " << options[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't see any reason why this might be giving errors, so I really don't even know where to begin fixing it :(

Comment: Options is a C-style array. It doesn't have a method `size`.

Comment: In c++ arrays are not class type and hence they don't have methods. You can take a look at `std::vector`.

Comment: `options` isn't a list, it's an array. Arrays don't have a size function, there is no way to determine the size of an array declared with `[]`

Comment: This is C++. This is not Java.

Comment: I was going to mention some things you can do with sizeof, but since this is a function argument, it's not even a C-style array. It's just a pointer. You have no information about the array boundaries other than what is passed in (low and high).

Comment: Don't learn C++ by trial and error. Get [a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Size Member Function Compile Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326807/array-size-member-function-compile-error)

Answer (score 4):

The declaration

```
string options[]
```

is equivalent to

```
string* options
```

in a function argument.

Given that, `options.size()` is wrong since pointers don't have any member functions.

I can think of the following options to get over that hurdle.

#### Option 1

Pass the size of the array as an argument to the function.

```
int getChoice(string options[], size_t size, int low, int high) {
```

and use it in the function.

#### Option 2

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a pointer.

```
int getChoice(std::vector<std::string> const& options, int low, int high) {
```

You can easily iterate over the contents of `options` using the range-`for` loop. If you need the size of the vector, you can use `options.size()`.

#### Option 3

If the size of the array is known at compile time, you may use `std::array<std::string, SIZE>` too.

```
const int SIZE = 10; // Just an example.

...

int getChoice(std::array<std::string, SIZE> const& options, int low, int high) {
```

As with `std::vector`, you may iterate over the contents of `options` using a range-`for` loop. If you need the size, it's available too in the form of `SiZE`.

Comment: The other hurdle to get over is to stop trying to learn C++ by analogy from some other programming language.   The OP is clearly familiar with some other programming language (Java, C#, ?) and is incorrectly assuming C++ does things the same way.   As long as they try to use C++ that way, they'll always be ineffective using C++.